# run 19c sqlldr throws - error while loading shared libraries: libnnz19.so

Tags: sql-loader, oracle19c

I have downloaded instantclient-tools-linux.x64-19.12.0.0.0dbru.zip on oracle enterprise linux 7 from oracle site and trying to run sqlldr cmd. Initially i got this error.

/scratch/guid/sqlldr/instantclient_19_12/sqlldr: error while loading shared libraries: libclntshcore.so.19.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

I copied all missing libs from oracle 19c database /lib location. Now, I have set ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH both pointing to /scratch/guid/sqlldr/instantclient_19_12 loc. When i run sqlldr cmd, i get this error..

linux version:
Linux den02ada 4.1.12-124.49.3.1.el7uek.x86_64

$ORACLE_HOME/sqlldr
Message 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=ULMessage 2100 not found; No message file for product=RDBMS, facility=UL[

Any work around to resolve this issue?

Comment: Don't set ORACLE_HOME when you are using Instant Client.   Don't hack and copy libs - that's a recipe for disaster.  Start again with a clean unzip of the Instant Client 'Basic' and 'Tools' packages.

Answer (score 0):

You've also downloaded the Base Package too?

Please mind that the basic Instant Client is required.

From the official site:

> Version 19.12.0.0.0 (Requires glibc 2.14)
> **Base - one of these packages is required**

The one you've downloaded is only an optional tools package, that requires one of the Instant Client Base Packages in order to work properly.

You can take get one of the Base Package here: https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

(*scroll down till you reach the 19.12 version*)

Comment: Thanks alot for this input. It worked after installing the base package.

Comment: No problem! :) Don't forget to mark the answer as the solution to your question